# how can we convert variable value into days?

Tags: solidity

i want to convert a value of variable into number of days! I have tried as follows, but got compile error at days!

```
function any(uint timeInDays) public 
{
uint256 TotalDays=timeInDays days;
}
```

Comment: Hi there. What is `timeInDays`? An integer holding a number of seconds?

Comment: it is variable of type uint256 !! @RichardHorrocks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation, These suffixes cannot be applied to variables. It should be done like this...
`uint256 numberOfDays = 5 days;`

If you want the value to come from a variable you would do it like the example below, base on the given example on the documentation.
Given that the timeInDays is equal to the desired number of days. Example: timeInDays = 5 to get the equivalent value of 5 days.

`uint256 TotalDays = timeInDays * 1 days;`

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/units-and-global-variables.html

Comment: I'm glad to help.